# Реализация методов в абстрактном классе (php)

Tags: php

Возник вопрос по теме абстрактных классов.
Вообщем я создал абстр-й класс Product от которого наследую классы NotebookProduct и BookProduct.
В классе Product написал абстр-й метод без тела abstract public function addMetod();
Вопрос мне нужно в обяз реализовать его в двух наследниках?
А если не хочу реализовывать, писать public function addMetod(){} в наследнике(иначе ошибка)?
Прошу объяснить новичку, буду благодарен.

Comment: все абстракные классы должны быть определены в классах наследниках, если вам не нужно реализовывать абстракный метод в наследнике, то скорее всего нет необходимсти делать этот метод абстрактным. вы можете его сделать публичным либо защищенным и при необходимости переопределить в классе наследнике.

Comment: абстрактный класс может содержать не только абстрактные методы. Как указано выше, видимо вам следует сделать этот метод обычным с пустым телом. при необходимости перекрыть в потомках. В инстнациируемых классах абстрактных методов оставаться не должно.